How should environment variables with sensitive data be stored in Angular app?
Could you suggest an approach of storing sensitive data in Angular app, similar to React environment variables which can be stored in .env file and accessed via process.env.REACT_APP_...?
There is no backend, only client side

Variables with sensitive data shouldn't have been stored in REACT_APP_ env vars - the whole point of the prefix is to make it clear that they're in the React app. There's no way to store sensitive information if you have only the client-side application.

Thanks for your comment. I solved the issue with npm package  @ngx-env/builder. Environment variables were defined, and everything works
